# Finding indices of two different groups in a python list into two lists

Tags: python

I have the below code as two list comprehensions, but I would like a way in which I only have to iterate over `edges` once.

```
        out_indices = [x for x, (p, d) in enumerate(edges) if d == "O"]
        in_indices = [x for x, (p, d) in enumerate(edges) if d == "I"]
```

I can do it with a very non-pythonic loop over `edges` and having two pre-initialized lists to put `x` into with two if statements, but I was wondering if there was a pythonic/prettier way to do this.

Comment: I wouldn't say that two pre-initialised lists is exactly un-pythonic... it's perfectly readable...

Comment: unless `enumerate(edges)` is expensive or has sideeffects (eg. maybe edges is a generator), I think it's easier to see what's going on with the two comprehensions, so I'd probably go with that

Comment: When did loops and `if` statements become un-Pythonic? If something is simple, clear, and understandable, chances are very high that it's Pythonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you'll just have to do what you wanted to avoid (not un-pythonic at all, by the way). Think about it- if you want to do it in one iteration you'd have to conditionally *append* to either list which obviously doesn't work with comprehensions:

```
out_indices = []
in_indices = []

for x, (p, d) in enumerate(edges):
    if d == 'O':
        out_indices.append(x)
    elif d == 'I':
        in_indices.append(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

For two, I'd just go with initialising the empty lists, however, if you had a lot of them, it might be better to store in a `dict`, eg:

```
data = 'OIIIOIIOOOIOOO'

d = {}
for i, v in enumerate(data):
    d.setdefault(v, []).append(i)

# {'I': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10], 'O': [0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13]}
```

Then access via `d['I']` or `d['O']` or if they're not guaranteed to be present use `d.get('I', [])` or  `d.get('O', [])` to get empty lists for non-present values.